# Remove all underscores in a column of dataframe

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
     Year   Country
[1,]  2008  Dortmund_Germany       
[2,]  2009  Ames_Iowa_USA
[3,]  2011  Rennes_France
```

I want to remove all underscores (_) in the second column. I tried it with gsub but it doesn´t provide me an appropriate result. What is the smartest way to do this?

Comment: @Sotos `sub` seems to work on factor columns, at least the output looks correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I removed the comment as soon as I run it on factors and worked. It usually is the problem though which is what misled me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df$Country <- gsub("_", "", df$Country)
```

The above should work, even if `Country` is a factor.

Comment: Why use regex? `df$Country <- gsub("_", "", df$Country, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now I know you watch the `gsub` tag.  Maybe I'll avoid this tag in the future.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I made a small but significant mistake!